# Splitting Dictionary Elements in Node Network

Tags: python

I am building a node network where the program will take in a list of locations that must be visited and output the shortest path. The full network is very large and iterating over the full thing takes an infeasibly long time so I am looking for ways to reduce the number of nodes without losing information.

My current problem is simplifying a row of nodes.

Each node in the row is a dictionary entry with the key being the name of the node and a list of each node that name be travelled to and the distance travelled.

ex. 'A1': [['A0', 3], ['A2', 3]] means, from node A1 you can travel to A0 with a movement cost of 3, and you can travel to A2 with a movement cost of 3.

Input

```
row = {'A0': [['A1', 3]], 
       'A1': [['A0', 3], ['A2', 3]],
       'A2': [['A1', 3], ['A3', 3]],
       'A3': [['A2', 3], ['A4', 3]],
       'A4': [['A3', 3], ['A5', 3]],
       'A5': [['A4', 3]]}

visit_list = ['A1', 'A3']
```

Output

```
output = {'A0': [['A1', 3]],
          'A1': [['A1', 3], ['A3', 6]],
          'A3': [['A1', 6], ['A5', 6]],
          'A5': [['A3', 6]]}
```

As you can see the output holds onto all the important information. A2 has been removed and the movement costs between A1 and A3 have been increased to account for that.

I'm not sure where to even begin with this, any tips/help is appreciated.